# Stack table cells one above each other two by two

Tags: html, css

In an HTML table, I'd like the 2nd and 3rd cell to be one above each other, as well as the the 4th and 5th, but the first cell must occupy the whole height of the row.

How to achieve this using CSS (I can't change the html markup)?

```css
table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-name,
table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-quantity,
table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-subtotal,
table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-remove {
  display: block;
}

table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-thumbnail {
  max-width: 92px;
}

table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-name {
  min-width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<table class="shop_table_responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
      <td class="product-thumbnail">
        <a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr/eshop/henleys-fr/henley-harri-stone/">
          <img width="324" height="324" src="https://staging.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/harri-stone-mysite-692X692-01-324x324.jpg">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-name" data-title="Produit" style="
             width: 150px;
             display: block;
             ">
        <div class="cart_product_name"><a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr/"><span class="cat_product_name_word1">Henley</span> <span class="cat_product_name_word2">Harri</span></a></div>
        <div class="cart_product_color"><a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr"> Stone</a></div>

      </td>
      <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantité">
        <div class="quantity wbu-quantity" dir="ltr">
          <a href="">-</a>
          <label class="screen-reader-text" for="qty_prod_34745_var_34763">quantité de Henley Harri - Stone</label>
          <input type="number">
          <a href="">+</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Sous-total" style="
             clear: both;
             ">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"> EUR</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="product-remove">
        <a href="www.google.com">×</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I know I can use `display: block;`on 2, 3, 4 and 5. But how to be sure that 4 is at the top ?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some css. Do you absolutely need it to be with tables ?

Comment: just did. I can't change the markup.

Comment: Are 3 and 4 exactly the same size ? if so you could use `position:relative`, or even `transform:translate(100%,-100%);`

Comment: No 3 and 4 are not necessary the same size

Comment: _“I can't change the html”_ - can’t – or just don’t want to? (Of course WooCommerce allows customizing of the cart output as well; it is just not all straight forward by editing templates, some of that stuff would need to be done via hooks/filters.)

Comment: Actually I am doing this only for the mobile version. So are there any hooks, only for mobile, so I can't change, remove, columns in the cart table (.shop_table_responsive)? I am using a child theme of Storefront.

Comment: No, there aren’t any hooks specifically for desktop or mobile, WordPress doesn’t do any device type detection that would influence the execution of those. I would try to find a non-table HTML structure that is suitable to be formatted how you need it for mobile, probably using flexbox for the formatting (and ordering, if necessary), and then try and re-create the look you need on desktop afterwards (via `display: table-*`)

Comment: No I can't change the markup, I am not the only one working on the project. So nobody has any idea how to stack cells two by two in table ?

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want you need to change the `display` of the table row. You can use either flex or grid for this. Below I have demonstrated using grid, with fixed widths of 33% for the columns, but changing this to "322px auto auto" will allow the thumbnail to be the correct width and the other columns to adjust automagically. By using Grid I have specified where I want the various cells to appear by using the `grid-xxx-start/end` properties.

```css
table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50fr 50fr;
  grid-template-columns: 33fr 33fr 33fr;
}

table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-thumbnail {
  max-width: 92px;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-quantity {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

table.shop_table_responsive tbody tr.cart_item td.product-name {
  min-width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<table class="shop_table_responsive">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item cart_item">
      <td class="product-thumbnail">1
        <a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr/eshop/henleys-fr/henley-harri-stone/">
          <img width="324" height="324" src="https://staging.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/harri-stone-mysite-692X692-01-324x324.jpg">
        </a>
      </td>
      <td class="product-name" data-title="Produit" style="
             width: 150px;
             display: block;
             ">2
        <div class="cart_product_name"><a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr/"><span class="cat_product_name_word1">Henley</span> <span class="cat_product_name_word2">Harri</span></a></div>
        <div class="cart_product_color"><a href="https://staging.mysite.com/fr"> Stone</a></div>

      </td>
      <td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantité">3
        <div class="quantity wbu-quantity" dir="ltr">
          <a href="">-</a>
          <label class="screen-reader-text" for="qty_prod_34745_var_34763">quantité de Henley Harri - Stone</label>
          <input type="number">
          <a href="">+</a>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="Sous-total" style="
             clear: both;
             ">4
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">70<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol"> EUR</span></span>
      </td>
      <td class="product-remove">5
        <a href="www.google.com">×</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For additional information, I recommend [A Complete Guide to CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

ok this is exaclty what I needed, for those interested, you can achieve it this way, using `flexbox`, setting the height of the row, and using `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` as follows:

```css
   .box {
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box div.one{
  height: 300px;
}
.box div.two,
.box div.three,
.box div.four,
.box div.five
{
  height: 148px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
  <div>Nine</div>
  <div>Ten</div>
</div>
```